# Python SQLite Insert operation

Tags: python, database, sqlite

this is the code from [Tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_python.htm) that i am looking at.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE COMPANY
   (ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
   AGE            INT     NOT NULL,
   ADDRESS        CHAR(50),
   SALARY         REAL);''')

conn.execute("INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) \
      VALUES (1, 'Paul', 32, 'California', 20000.00 )");   

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

how do i add an integer variable to one of the values, let say AGE.For example, i tried this but i got a value error:

```
p=32
conn.execute("INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) \
             VALUES(1,'Paul',?,'California',20000.00)",p)
```

Do i have to store all the variable in the list then add to the database like this?

```
list = [(1,'Paul',32,'California',20000.00)]
for item in list:
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) \
                 VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)",item)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass parameter value as list or tuple:

```
p = 32
conn.execute("INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) \
             VALUES(1,'Paul',?,'California',20000.00)", [p])
```

According to the [DB API specification](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15):

> ```
> .execute(operation [, parameters])
> ```
>
> ...
>   Parameters may be provided as **sequence or mapping** and will be bound to
>   variables in the operation. ...